# React-router wrong matching when navigating with Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes:

```
function getModalRoutes() {
  return (
    <Route component={ ModalContainer }>
      <Route path='login' component={ SessionContainer }/>
      <Route path='registration' component={ RegistrationContainer } />
    </Route>
  );
}

<Provider store={ createStoreWithState() }>
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/object/:object_id/" component={ ShowRoute } >
      { getModalRoutes() }
    </Route>
    <Route path="/" component={ IndexRoute } >
      { getModalRoutes() }
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

If I access `/object/1/login` the matching works correctly. If I use a link like the one below for navigation, from `/object/1/` page, the `/login` route is matched instead of `/object/:object_id/login`.

```
<Link
  to={ `login` }
  className="btn">
  Log In
</Link>
```

Is there a different way to use the `Link` for this scenario? I feel like I am missing something here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `login` link to `/object/1/login`. You can also parameterize it like `/object/${number}/login`. In general, when you navigate inside your app with links like `/your_link`, you always get to `http://yourdomain.sth/your_link`.